# Solving listobject paste special - Run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I would like to move all of the data from one table into 4 other tables. I am getting a pastespecial error using the code below. The code is quite long so a relevant snippet is posted below.

```
Set tbl2 = ws1.ListObjects("Table2")
Set tbl3 = ws2.ListObjects("Table3")
Set tbl4 = ws3.ListObjects("Table4")
Set tbl5 = ws4.ListObjects("Table5")

For i = 1 To tbl1.ListRows.Count
    tbl1.ListRows(i).Range.Copy

    tbl2.ListRows.Add 1, True
    tbl2.ListRows(1).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    tbl2.ListRows(1).Range.Value = tbl1.ListRows(i).Range.Value

    tbl3.ListRows.Add 1, True
    tbl3.ListRows(1).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    tbl3.ListRows(1).Range.Value = tbl1.ListRows(i).Range.Value


    tbl4.ListRows.Add 1, True
    tbl4.ListRows(1).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    tbl4.ListRows(1).Range.Value = tbl1.ListRows(i).Range.Value

    tbl5.ListRows.Add 1, True
    tbl5.ListRows(1).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    tbl5.ListRows(1).Range.Value = tbl1.ListRows(i).Range.Value

Next i
```

"Run time error 1004":
Pastespecial of range class failed

This error is triggered by the first paste special line.

Any ideas on how to correct this issue? I have searched on stacked for a while but have not yet found a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you want to `.Copy` something immediately before you go and `PasteSpecial` it - is `ListRows.Add` losing the `CutCopyMode`? Does `tbl2` have the same number of columns as `tbl1`?

Comment: Hi Mathieu thanks for the comment. I moved all of the pastespecial immediately under the copy and it is no longer giving me an error  - great news! - but is taking a considerable amount of time to compute. Is there a cleaner way of moving the listrow and it's format to another table?

Comment: See below answer; hope it helps!

Comment: [Here's an important note](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/2/26/caution-creating-creating-pastespecial-macros) to keep in mind when using `PasteSpecial`. I know this situation has tripped me several times when debugging code (that otherwise would have worked!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're simply appending the contents of `tbl1` to a bunch of other tables.

Instead of involving the clipboard, copy the source `DataBodyRange` to a 2D variant array:

```
Dim content As Variant
content = tbl1.DataBodyRange.Value
```

Then add a new row to your destination:

```
tbl2.ListRows.Add
```

And dump your 2D array at that location:

```
tbl2.ListRows(tbl2.ListRows.Count).Range.Resize(UBound(content, 1)).Value = content
```

Rinse & repeat for every destination table... should be pretty much instant.

Comment: Hi Mathieu thanks again for your help yesterday. A quick follow up question. I have a column that hold text values like "2-10" and "3-12" that are converted to the text-date format something like "43477" & 43475" when they are moved from one table to another. ANy suggestions on how to keep the original text or convert back?

Comment: @Dmegaffi argh, Excel being "helpful" again... You can format these columns as text in the destination tables, should fix it. Or, prepend these values with a single quote in the source data.